# Can I create a data.frame in R from an existing data.frame by assigning a list of col.names?

Tags: r, dataframe, names, renaming

I have a data.frame where I assign each column.name a vector of variables:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=1:5,c=1:5)
```

I want to create a new data.frame but instead of assigning each column individually, I want to assign them all at once. For example, if I wanted to rename them all:

```
dat.new <- data.frame(paste(names(dat1),'1',sep='') = dat1)
```

This obviously doens't work. Is there a way to make it work?

I understand I can just rename using `names()`, but the scenario where this actually seems useful is if combining multiple data sets that share the same col.names (and in which I don't want to simply rbind):

```
dat1 <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=1:5,c=1:5)
dat2 <- data.frame(a=6:10,b=6:10,c=6:10)
dat.new <- data.frame(paste(names(dat1),'1',sep='') = dat1, paste(names(dat1),'2',sep='') = dat2)
```

Comment: Is this what you want: `data.frame(setNames(dat1, paste0(names(dat1), "1")), setNames(dat2, paste0(names(dat1), "2")))`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
```

Ok, here's the first part:

```
dat2 = 
  dat1 %>%
  setNames(names(.) %>% 
             paste0("1") )
```

Here's the second part. The reshaping is a bit complex but more flexible, especially if you have row id's already with different amounts of rows:

```
list(dat1, dat2) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "number") %>%
  group_by(number) %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -number, -id) %>%
  unite(new_variable, variable, number) %>%
  spread(new_variable, value)
```